# Send mail using php and postfix

Tags: php, html, email

Thank you for taking the time to review my question.
I have postfix set up on Centos 6.4 I am not very familiar with E-mail servers or PHP, but I would like to set up a simple sight to send emails using postfix. I was told I should use php. My current. (not working) source code is this...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mainContainer
{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
}

#adressContainer
{
        width:100%;
        height:3%;
}

#buttonContainer
{
        width:100%;
        height:5%;
}

#bodyContainer
{
        width:100%;
        height:90%;
}

#address
{
        resize:none;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
}

#bodyText
{
        resize:none;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
}
</style>
<script>

        <?php
        function sendMail()
        {

                $to = "someone@somewhere"
                $subject = "Test mail";
                $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
                $headers = "From:" . $from;
                mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        }       
        ?>
</script>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="email.css" />-->
</head>
<body>
        <div id="mainContainer">
                <div id="addressContainer">
                        <input id="adress" type="text" name="Adress: "></input>
                </div>

                <div id="buttonContainer">
                        <button type="submit" onclick="sendMail()">send</button>
                </div>

                <div id="bodyContainer">
                        <textarea id="bodyText">I love you whitney :) </textArea>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mail servers are complicated. This mix of HTML and php doesn't tell us what we need to know. Postfix has a lot of configuration that needs to be done properly

Comment: Remember to put the ending semi-colon with Marc B's answer, if you're going to use some of your old code. Old => `$to = "someone@somewhere"` new => `$to = "someone@somewhere.com";`

Comment: @relentless yes, I am aware. Mark B's anwer helped me with my php but I'm still not sending emails through the mail function. which I did not expect to happen anyways. I have postfix running correctly and I can send mail from the command line, now I just have to link the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP runs on the server. `onClick` executes Javascript on the **CLIENT** machine. You can **NOT** directly invoke PHP functions via Javascript code, or vice versa.

What you're doing can be accomplished with a simple form:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]  == 'POST') {
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    mail($to, .....);
}

?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="to" />
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

There is no need to use Javascript at all.